# Reacting to incoming notifications (from any app) and playing a sound

Tags: android

I want to write an app that would play a sound whenever the phone receives a notification, such as new Email received or a new WhatsApp message came in.

Notice that the notification is coming from 3rd party app.
I don't want to read the content of the notification, just react to the fact that it happened.

Is it possible? What are the APIs to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to write an app that would play a sound whenever the phone receives a notification

That is already part of the operating system. You do not need to write an app for that. On modern versions of Android, users have quite a bit of control over [notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) (see "Apps & notifications" in Settings).

> Is it possible? What are the APIs to use.

You would need to implement a `NotificationListenerService`.

> I don't want to read the content of the notification, just react to the fact that it happened.

A `NotificationListenerService` gets access to the content of the `Notification`, so you get that content whether you like it or not. As a result, the user will be warned of the security issues involved with the use of your app, and you may encounter difficulty in distributing it through the Play Store (if Google does not believe that your app is valuable to the user).